# Symfony 2 global functions

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to have a set of global functions available to my Symfony 2 app (across multiple controllers and entities) which act like built in PHP functions. For example:

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return !strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle));
}
```

I can create a file with these functions in it, but it needs to be duplicated for each namespace:

```
namespace Taggle\TaggleBundle\DependencyInjection;
namespace Taggle\TaggleBundle\Controller;
```

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Why does it need to be duplicated for different namespaces? Just declare them in the global one? And why not define them as classes with static methods?

Comment: I'm not sure how to declare them in a global namespace. That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the file with your function declarations does not define a namespace, your functions are declared in the global namespace.

Functions in the global namespace can be called from within any other namespace by their regular name.

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function foo() {
  echo 'bar';
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar;

require 'functions.php';

foo(); // 'bar'
```

However, I would recommend against defining plain functions this way. First of all they pollute the global namespace (leading to potential naming clashes), and secondly you are much better off declaring a class with static methods. That way you can also benefit from the autoloading mechanism.

Comment: Thanks! If it's not too much to ask, could you point me to some example documentation for using the Symfony2 autoloading mechanism?